# python gir / Gtk.Image: why does it corrupt my image?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject

I'm working with an external api which returns an Gtk.Image object.
I'm trying to write that Gtk.Image to a file. 
To illustrate the problem I've created the following code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import cStringIO

i = Gtk.Image()
i.set_from_file('/home/leon/Pictures/msn/ikea.jpg')

p = i.get_pixbuf()

f = open('/tmp/test.png', 'wb+')

def write(*args, **kwargs):
    f.write(args[0])
    return True

# ubuntu 11.10 doesn't have pixbuf.save_to_callback so instead use save_to_callbackv
p.save_to_callbackv(write, None, "png", [], [])

f.close()
```

The file gets written to disk but is corrupted. Why is it corrupted?

Comment: You probably want to write binary. Use 'wb'.

Comment: When using 'wb' I get the same error :(

Comment: you get an error? Or you get a corrupted image? Are the image attributes (size, color depth, etc.) all correct, just the contents are garbled? How are they messed up? I don't know this library, so just looking for clues.

Comment: Sorry, not python gives an error but the image viewer:
`Fatal error reading PNG image file: [08][08][08][DB]: invalid chunk type`

Comment: When converting it to a bmp the viewer reports: `BMP image has unsupported header size`

Comment: An example of the viewer: http://i.snag.gy/q3eUh.jpg

Comment: I can confirm the issue - I also get broken PNG image.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit shorter (and working) version:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

i = Gtk.Image()
i.set_from_file('/home/leon/Pictures/msn/ikea.jpg')

p = i.get_pixbuf()
p.savev('/tmp/xxx.png', 'png', [], [])
```

Though, I'm not sure what goes wrong with your version :S

Comment: Yep, that works! But I would like to use a filedescriptor. So I can use cStringIO and stream that to urllib.

Comment: Maybe you can then use gdkpixbuf.save_to_stream for this purpose?

Comment: I also thought about that, but: `filter(lambda x: re.match("save", x), dir(p))` returns:
`['save_to_bufferv', 'save_to_callbackv', 'save_to_stream_finish', 'savev']`

I believe the whole python gir pixbuf to be horribly broken...

Comment: oh, well.. bugs.gnome.org then :)

Comment: I've mailed to the python-hackers mailing list first. Maybe they'll have an answer.